# Firefox executes both if and else?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I run into this pretty weird thing into firefox, probably I'm missing something but somehow both the if and the else clause in the following code gets executed?

```
if($.fx.off)
{
    widget.css({opacity: 1});
}
else
{
    widget.delay(delay).animate({top: "+=100"},10).animate({top: "-=100",opacity: 1}, 1000);
}
```

When tracing ff starts with the if line, moves to: `widget.css({opacity: 1});`, and afterwards it continues executing: `widget.delay(delay).animate({top: "+=100"},10).animate({top: "-=100",opacity: 1}, 1000);`??

Anybody a clue what is going on?

`$.fx.off` is defined as off in this case.

A self contained minimal example would be:

```
$.fx.off = false;
if($.fx.off)
{
    alert('me');
}
else
{
    alert('and me to!');
}
```

However I doubt it replicates....

Comment: Do you have some minimal self-contained example for others to observe the behavior, too?

Comment: Added the minimal self-contained example which reuquires JQuery because of the `$.fx.off`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by 2 individual faults. One i made an error somewhere else in the code, which excecutes a code pretty similar to the else case, so it seemed the else case was executed. and the second the debug (step by step) in firefox seems pretty dodgy. it marks lines that do not get executed.

I found this by implementing the minimal example an running it from the code. The alerts both get a mark as if they are executed, however at the one that is not executed it does not run. So i't an error in the debugger.

Then i searched the code for the animation and found it to be an error combined with a css3 animation tag.

Problem solved

Comment: Glad to see it. It’s good practice in such case to mark your own answer with the green checkmark.

Comment: I'm willing to, but if i try it notify's me that i need to wait another day in able to be allowed to markt my own answer as answered... (apparantly this is only possible after 2 days.)

Comment: You encountered a Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1013219